# Magento group prices for simple products associated with configurable products

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, price, simple-product, group

I would like to know if it's possible in magento 1.8.0 to show different group prices for a simple product that is part of a configurable product.

I have a configurable product (T-shirt) and i have 5 simple products (for 5 different colors) that are associated with the configurable product.

When i create group prices for the configurable product they do show on the frontend.

But how do i proceed if, for example, the red t-shirt costs more than the blue one?

In the admin panel I can save different group prices for each simple product, but they don't show up on the website.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you solve your point?

Answer (score 3):

Group price will be applied across the board, however, you can still supply an over-ride on the associated products tab.

Let's say, for example, you set the grouped price for General to $10.00.  You can see in the screenshot below that I have specified a fixed increase of $5.00 for the Blue t-shirt option.  Thus, the price on the frontend would be $10.00 but if you select the Blue option, it will be $15.00.

That satisfy your needs?

[image]

Comment: I would like to set this fixed increase individually for each customergroup. Is that possible? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not that I know of outside of adding that functionality programmatically.  I could be wrong, however.